# For stop work when my object is copied without referency

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to remove one attribute from my object (indexvariacaoatributo), but i need that the attribute stay in the root object.

This is my algorithm that receive from the variable variacoes my object and after i remove the attribute indexvariacaoatributo from my object, this way works but too remove from my root object:

```
var variacoes = categoriaForm.variacoes
if(variacoes[0].estoque_variacao == null || variacoes[0].estoque_variacao == 0){
  variacoes = [];
}
//Retira do objeto o indexvariacaoatributo
for(let i=0;i<variacoes.length;i++){
  for (let j=0;j<variacoes[i].atributo.length;j++){
    console.log(variacoes[i].atributo[j].indexvariacaoatributo);
    delete variacoes[i].atributo[j].indexvariacaoatributo
  }
}
```

console.log(variacoes);

I try to copy without referency in this ways:

```
var variacoes = Object.assign({}, categoriaForm.variacoes);
```

Also tried:

```
var variacoes = { ...categoriaForm.variacoes };
```

But when i print my variable variacao i see that my attribute still stay in my object. I put a console.log and don't print the element inside the for.

There's something more that i need to do when i copy the object in this way?

Thanks

Comment: Try var variacoes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categoriaForm.variacoes)). This makes sure that changes to one does not affect the other and so the issue of copying can be avoided